# delayed job does not call the method defined with .delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I am using Rails 4.0.1 and performing delayed_job for sending emails.

The issue I am facing is if I call an invitation method

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
    def send_email(invitation_obj)
        InvitationMailer.delay.invitation(invitation_obj)
    end
end
```

Consider it is being called in a loop for 6 times.

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "some@one.com"
end

class InvitationMailer < BaseMailer
    def invitation(invitation_obj)
        mail(subject: "Sub", to: invitation_obj.email)
    end
end
```

Now, the issue what I am facing is this does not always log an actual method call.

```
[Worker(host:myhost pid:32328)] Job ApplicationMailer.invitation (id=21) RUNNING
[Worker(host:myhost pid:32328)] Job ApplicationMailer.invitation (id=21) COMPLETED after 3.0054
```

Above execution for 3/6 requests of delayed_job works perfect and sends an email too.
But sometimes it logs

```
[Worker(host:myhost pid:32328)] Job PerformableMailer.method (id=21) RUNNING
```

And above execution does not even send an email.

Can anyone please tell me what behavior is this for a delayed job and why it is executing PerformableMailer and not InvitationMailer for some requests.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of the delayed job daemon running, with one having an old version of your classes?

Comment: Could be. Can you please tell me how to check for running instances? When I check for running processes for delayed_job with ps -aux | grep delayed_job it gives only one process. @struthersneil

Comment: Also, have a read of this (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/267) and see if it helps. Personally I'm not a fan of adding a .delay method to every object that works by magic--I prefer to create a job class and explicitly call perform_later on it, and that approach has always worked for me without an issue.

Comment: @struthersneil I already have checked the link but did not help in fixing this. There can be a multiple instances as you noted but I don't know how to check that, if you can help me out with that too. Also I will try creating a job class and check if it works. Is there any link that you know which explains best working with Job class

Comment: Sounds like you only have one instance of delayed_job then. Try dumping your Delayed::Job table after creating each job and observe what type and method is associated with the job.

Comment: @struthersneil it shows PerformableMailer::method if I check Delayed::Job.find(id) entry for a particular job

Comment: Just search the readme for Custom Jobs: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: @ArthThakkar any update on this? Having the same issue right now.

Comment: @mmichael Yes as per the first comment check if there are multiple instances running. Just have one instance of delayed job worker running